# How to get thrift type of an attribute?

Tags: ruby, thrift

I would like to process many attributes automatically.
But my data are read from a file and they are string type...
I would like to know if there is a solution to know the type of attribute.
Thanks to this, I'll be able to convert string into the right type.

```
struct Test{
1: i32 id,
2: string name,
3: Enumeration genre
}

test = Test.new
```

A method which does (for example) :

```
puts test.id.type  => Give me i32
puts test.name.type  => Give me string
```

Etc..

I can use test.id.class but it doesn't work .. (it tells me nilClass when it isn't assigned)

And even if "id" is a i32,

```
test.id = "blabla"  => works... (normally, it shouldn't)
```

The verification of type is done only when you try to serialize... not when you assign a value into a thrift object.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: `Thrift.type_checking=true`, will cause exception to be raised if type does not match

```
>> Thrift.type_checking
=> false
>> Thrift.type_checking=true
=> true
>> test=Test.new
=> Test id:nil, name:nil
>> test.id="Hi"
Thrift::TypeError: Expected Types::I32, received String for field id
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thrift-0.9.1.1/lib/thrift/types.rb:69:in `check_type'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thrift-0.9.1.1/lib/thrift/struct.rb:157:in `id='
    from (irb):4
```

---

**Orig answer**

Not sure exactly what you are looking for but seems to look for thrift-specific reflection

You can get the list of member types of a struct, if that helps

`test.struct_fields.each{|fid,v| puts "#{fid}: #{v[:name]} #{v[:type]}"}`

And you can also get the field ID as key into `struct_fields` if you took the struct class
and referenced the field name (all caps), so could you do something with this?

```
test.struct_fields[Test::ID][:type]
```

Value can be matched against constants in `Thrift::Types` such as `I16`

<del>You can also use the validate method on the struct, after you assigned (so you can avoid failing the serialization)</del>
**Edit**: I misspoke - the validate method does not validate values, just that required fields exist.
I guess there is no such thing, as the current validation happens in the specific protocols.  You could just attempt serialization if you wanted or just write a generic validator that for a given field it uses the type (as seen above) to test

That having been said - I checked out the library code thinking that the generated accessors could be modified to do it, And it looks like they may have that capability already, see https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/rb/lib/thrift/struct.rb#L157

Comment: Yes I succeed today ... but it was too late to delete this post. Thank you nhed !
I was able to find the list in Types.rb (in /lib/rb/lib of thrift)

It's not useful to use... (I have to have a hash with name and id)

And to assign a value into an attribute with "enum", Thrift doesn't convert string into number ID of enum and then I have to use const_get etc...

How it's possible to validate a struct ? (Now, I try serialization to know ... )

Comment: Updated answer - the `validate` method just validates that required fields are populated.  My bad.

Comment: One more edit, as I may have found what you have been looking for

Comment: Thank you nhed ! You are the only one who code thrift with ruby...
I'm finishing what I have begun and I try "Thrift.type_checking=true".
My current method (obj.struct_fields[Object.const_get(name_of_class)::const_get(name.upcase)][:type]  and a hash  number=>type's name ) works fine.

Comment: @user3604482 you are welcome, but I'm sure that there are plenty (they are just busy), I just happened to monkey-patched some stuff the past in the read/write parts so I knew where to look

Comment: oh ok, So do I , I think that they are busy !
Thank you again :)